# Debug a lambda capturing this

Tags: c++, c++11, lldb

I have a lambda that captures `this`. When I debug it I have trouble seeing members of the captures object: if I do a `p *this`, LLDB prints:

```
((anonymous class)) $1 = {
  this = 0x17ebb62c
}
```

So apparently I have the lambda's class that contain only one member, which is the `this` pointer it has captured. Seems legit, so I tried `p this->this` and then it reports:

```
error: expected unqualified-id
```

I fear that LLDB is lost because this is both a keyword and a member of my anonymous class. Is that the case? What can I do to circumvent that?

Comment: Could you paste some code that you are trying, please?

Comment: It all amount to: `[this]()
    {
        // code I am trying to debug
    });`

Comment: Sorry hard to say what is going on with this little information, try to elaborate your question, e.g. what is `p`, etc.

Comment: This is where a [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, thank you for looking at my problem, but my question is about lldb, and I need someone with actual knowledge of it

Comment: @Yuki: `p` is the "shortcut" of `print`.

Comment: @GuillaumeGuigue: how about `print this->member` directly, or even `print member` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the following code:

```
struct S
{
    auto f() { return [this](){ return ++i; }; }
    int i = 0;
};
```

I find it sometimes necessary to proceed in two passes:

```
> break S::f
> continue
...
> print *this
((anonymous class)) $1 = {
  this = 0x17ebb62c
}
> print (S*)0x17ebb62c
S $2 = {
    i = 0
}
```

Comment: This works for the command line, but any idea how to make this work in a GUI debugger like CLion? When I try and watch a variable from inside a lambda e.g. "this->this->myVar" I am encountering this issue.